# Apex Collection: how to have actual column names instead of C001, C002

Tags: collections, oracle-apex

created a page to allow users to input SQL statement, when user press button, it should Execute this query and another region with Classic Report will display results.
on Button a Dynamic Action execute PL/SQL code below:
on Click event:

```
begin
IF :P8_YOURSQL IS NOT NULL THEN
APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY (
p_collection_name => 'SOMECOLLECTION',
p_query => :P8_YOURSQL,
p_truncate_if_exists => 'YES'
);
end if;
end;
```

Item to Submit: P8_YOURSQL

second Action refreshes CR region and CR region is based on:

```
SELECT * FROM APEX_COLLECTIONS
WHERE COLLECTION_NAME = 'SOMECOLLECTION';
```

resulted columns are not limited to the query results and column headers are C001, C002, C003 etc.
(a) how i can limit the columns to the SQL statement contained?
(b) how to change header to the actual column names?
(c) how to check for a valid SQL statement?

please help with sample code How To.

Answer (score 3):

`APEX_COLLECTIONS` is a generic table so it has a couple of columns for the most common data types with names like `C001, N001` etc. As with any table columns can be aliased in a query.

Example:

- Create page process before header to populate the collection

```
APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY (
  p_collection_name => 'EMP_COLLECTION',
  p_query => q'!SELECT * FROM emp!',
  p_truncate_if_exists => 'YES'
);
```

- Run the page and open the "Session" window from the developer toolbar. Select "Collections" in the "View" dropdown and click "Set". This will list the data in the APEX_COLLECTIONS table for any collections that exist for the session. Take note of the data and the columns the data is in.
- Leave the "Sessions" window open and create a sql query on the APEX_COLLECTIONS view with appropriate aliases.

```
SELECT 
  c001 as EMPNO,
  c002 as ENAME, 
  c003 as JOB, 
  c004 as MGR, 
  <rest_of_columns>...
 FROM
  APEX_COLLECTIONS WHERE collection_name = 'EMP_COLLECTION'
```

It's not possible to alias columns when doing a `SELECT * FROM ...`

If the `SELECT *`  is important then there is another possibility. Create a view on top of `APEX_COLLECTIONS` with relevant column names. Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE view EMP_COLLECTION_V 
AS
SELECT 
  c001 as EMPNO,
  c002 as ENAME, 
  c003 as JOB, 
  c004 as MGR
 FROM
  APEX_COLLECTIONS WHERE collection_name = 'EMP_COLLECTION'
```

and then use `SELECT * FROM EMP_COLLECTION_V` as SQL source for the classic report.

Comment: thanks @Koen Lostire, sorry if i failed to describe, during my search for this requirement i found the following Carsten Czarski blog topic https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/super-easy-csv-xlsx-json-or-xml-parsing-about-the-apex-data-parser-package , here he showed how to get actual column names but did not illustrate how to use instead C001, C002 etc. this is what can be used dynamically no matter which query i run. i failed to find a solution yet. regards

Comment: Check my other answer. From what I understand now this question is about how to get the column names for any query - not about apex_collections

Answer (score 2):

To get the columns names for a `SELECT * FROM ...` have a look at [DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS3][https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-00AB5DE3-C428-4E60-9398-FD4892F32402]. There is an example in the doc that shows how to print the column names.

This can then be implemented in a classic report

- Create a page item per column: P1_C1, P1_C2, etc
- Set the column header for each column to the corresponding page item: col1 has header &P1_C1, col2 has header &P1_C2, etc
- Create a page process to set the column headers based on the sql query using DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS3 - OR - use a

Note that it is strongly advised to assert the sql query to avoid unwanted sql (like a delete or drop table command).

Comment: hi Koen Lostire, i found a solution by @Vinish at orclqa.com which is working fine. the link to my topic at orclqa.com is: https://orclqa.com/question/apex-collection-how-to-have-actual-column-names-instead-of-c001-c002/#comment-2083 ( you can download his sample app from his post ) regards.

Comment: That approach is similar to the one I described.